# Why is it quicker to search on google app compared to web browser on smartphones

Tags: iphone, ipad, search, google

When you do a google search , the time taken for the results and the webpages of the result to load is much faster on Google search app compared to web browser for smartphones. What is the explaination behind this ??

Google app

[image]

Web Browser

[image]

Comment: Much quicker is based on?

Comment: @Robuust Loading times of the results page and the webpages of the results

Answer (score 1):

Your screen shot shows EDGE networking which is one of the slowest in terms of bandwidth and often also in latency.

Presumably, the Google app can send just the characters you type to the search engine immediately and get just the results you need to see back.

The web page has to redraw the entire page when results start to arrive, so if you are noticing a sustained, long term speedup in one versus the other then you can conclude one of several things:

1. The native app sends less data and retrieves less data - but interacts with the same servers (or more precisely - servers with the same speed) on google's side.
2. The native app sends the same data as the web app but connects to servers that respond faster.

I would guess both are in play. Google is selling you and your searches to Google's paying customers. It doesn't take deep analysis or insight to realize that Google gets more value from you using their native app than it does from you using safari to browse their web search app. It might easily serve Google's interests to invest more money in making you choose the tool that makes it the most money.